# Is there has a way to let other people add my GAS to their account?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have already written a GAS that can give me a notice on Line Notify depends on my calendar event.
Now I want to write a simple website to let my friend just input his calendarID and Linenotifytoken then the GAS that with the input information will auto into his account and triggered.
I know if he copy my code is the fastest. But I want to use another way.